# Angular CLI application change environment property in production

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-forms, angular2-services, environment

Im new with angular 2/4 and have this issue, I want to be able to change properties without restarting the server or re deploying the application.

I want to be able to change properties IN PRODUCTION

I know if I have some properties in ***environment.prod.ts*** when I run

> ng build --prod --aot

this properties will be in the ***main.js*** file in the dist folder.

I want to know what I have to do if I want to change some property without re build the project.

Comment: you can type ng serve

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to be able to change properties IN PRODUCTION*

You cannot change properties for the production version without rebuilding the app via

`ng build --prod --aot`

There is nothing actively monitoring the source code in the /dist folder. You also wouldn't want errors (such as typos, syntax errors, even accidents) to affect your production code.

It's good practice to to test everything locally via

`ng serve`

and then build your final production distribution when you are ready.

**Side Note from [Docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve):**

> When running ng serve, the compiled output is served from memory, not from disk. This means that the application being served is not located on disk in the dist folder.